Не могу придумать подходящий способ реализации взаимодействия Unity3D
Моя система взаимодействия с объектами устроена так:
Скрипт выпускает из камеры игрока луч определённой длины. Сталкиваясь с объектом, он проверяет его тег. Если тег - "Look", то скрипт луча вызовет находящийся на этом объекте скрипт, который запустит диалог. Здесь всё просто, ведь скрипт, запускающий диалог, всегда один и тот же. Т.е я всегда знаю название скрипта и могу воспользоваться GetComponent. Однако, если тег объекта - "Use", то скрипт луча вновь должен вызвать скрипт на объекте... но скриптов взаимодействия может быть неограниченное количество и я не могу точно знать, какой скрипт лежит на объекте.

Что значит "скриптов взаимодействия может быть неограниченное количество" ? Если вы знаете, что у Use Надо взять конкретный компонент, то не ясно в чём проблема

Просто довольно странно если будет 1000 объектов с тегом Use и всех у них будет разные компоненты.

Я добавил скриншот принципа работы системы взаимодействия. На объекте может висеть скрипт, скажем, "IsUse_OpenDoor" или "IsUse_TakeItem". Эта система не может заранее знать, какой из этих скриптов будет висеть на интерактивном объекте, поэтому я не уверен, что стоит делать в такой ситуации.

Код надо вставлять текстом.

GetComponent можно вызывать для родителя скрипта. Сделайте у всех этих скриптов общего родителя, пусть у него будет метод StartInteract() и переопределите его при наследовании. Получится самый обыкновенный полиморфизм. ООП сила!


На объекте может скрипт, скажем, "IsUse_OpenDoor" или "IsUse_TakeItem". Эта система не может заранее знать, какой из этих скриптов будет висеть на интерактивном объекте, поэтому я не уверен, что стоит делать в такой ситуации.

Для таких случаев придумали как минимум интерфейсы и SOLID (а ещё есть шаблоны проектирования...)
Должен быть общий интерфейс, например interface IUsable с методом Use. Далее куча компонентов, которая должна реализовывать этот интерфейс. А при взятии компонента будет использоваться именно имя интерфейса общего hit.transform.GetComponent<IUsable> и у него вызываться метод Use
Всё очень просто. Надо изучать основы программирования

Я уже пробовал использовать интерфейсы, но постоянно стопорился на каком-то моменте. Что ж, пока это кажется лучшим вариантом... видимо, стоит продолжить в этом направлении. Спасибо!

"но постоянно стопорился на каком-то моменте" --- вот с этим моментом и надо приходить и задавать вопрос на стаке)

Я старался верить, что проблема в способе, а не в исполнителе)

@QEvvv а вы попробовали то, что в этом ответе предложено? Если нет, то о чём речь? Если да, то что именно не получается?

@aepot ранее я немного неправильно реализовывал предложенный способ с интерфейсами, однако сейчас всë работает как надо

@QEvvv чтобы принять ответ как полезный, нужно поставить зелёную галочку слева от него.
